# In OpenBSD how to upgrade individual system files like (grep, rcs, rlog ) to latest version?

Tags: package, chroot, dokuwiki, openbsd, foswiki

I am attempting to run foswiki on OpenBSD. Things are installed and i am able to open `"/bin/Configure"` page of foswiki configuration screen.  but the page reports few errors, complaining that following files are either not found or outdated and new versions are required.

**The Files are :   grep, rcs, ci, co,rlog, rcsdiff**

I tried commands like *`"pkg_add -Uu"`* to upgrade packages installed, but it reports all packages are uptodate.

I also tried *`"pkg_add rcs"  "pkg_add grep"`*   etc    but non works.

So my basic question is how to I update above files to their latest version required by foswiki.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

While I’m not familiar with Foswiki, my first thought is your web server is chrooted, as this is the default on OpenBSD, and, as a result, Foswiki cannot find the files it needs.  You can copy the files Foswiki needs into the chroot or run the web server without chroot, which is bad from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

all programs mentioned are part of a base openbsd install and the above answer is correct. the [openbsd documentation on chrooted apache](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq10.html#httpdchroot) has more info.

if you don't have to stick with foswiki you can try [dokuwiki](http://openports.se/www/dokuwiki) instead which has package support on openbsd and installs easily in very much the same way you tried already:

```
sudo pkg_add -U dokuwiki
```

hope the process is pretty much self-descriptive. in addition, the [manpage for pkg_add](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pkg_add&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html) is a good thing to read. good luck!